auto_arima from pmdarima has insane execution times increases at the growing of m, what's the cause?
I'm trying to fit a SARIMA model for my time series, in order to find the best model I'm using autom_arima from pmdarima. The code is simply:
stepwise_fit = pm.auto_arima(train_dataset['shift_hours'], start_p=1, start_q=1,
                             max_p=3, max_q=3, m=365,
                             start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                             d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                             error_action='ignore',  
                             suppress_warnings=True,  
                             stepwise=True)  

Where 'train_dataset['shift_hours']' is composed of roughly two years of daily values that have a seasonality with a period of 365 days.
The problem I'm encountering concerns the execution time: when m is set with value 1, it takes less than a second to perform a step in the stepwise search, when it's 7 or 12 the execution time for a step sits between 1 and 2 seconds, but when I set m with the value 365 (the one that I need) it takes more than 30 minutes to perform a SINGLE step. If I use the girdsearch with n_jobs > 4 i get a memory error.
For what I know about SARIMA, it shouldn't take more tiem to fit a series when I use a bigger period, because the number of terms that it uses to model the series doesn't depend on m, so I'm wondering what it's happening down there and if there is something going on that I'm not understanding
